# Show that a polynomial has at least one positive solution/root.

Tags: polynomials

Let: $P(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + ..... + a_1x + a_0$ where $a_0a_n < 0$
I have to prove that the Polynomial $P(x)$ has at least one positive root
**how can I prove it? Any ideas?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For $x$ very large, $P(x)\approx a_n x^n$ and so has a sign different from that of $P(0)=a_0$ since $a_0a_n<0$. By the intermediate value theorem, there is a positive root.

Comment: well,i almost understand your answer but can you tell me where to use this : a0an < 0 . It is given from the exercise. can you be more specific?. i would be grateful

Comment: $a_0a_n<0$ means that $a_0$ and $a_n$ have different signs.

Comment: +1, I like this way (though it sounds more abstract in nature)..

Comment: awesome help! i completely understand.

If there is anyone with another solution he/she is welcome to give it!
thanks!